# How can I find a cell, which contain a picture in apache poi

Tags: java, image, excel, apache-poi

I try to loop images in xls document. I write next code:

```
HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
if (patriarch != null) {
    // Loop through the objects
    for (HSSFShape shape : patriarch.getChildren()) {
        if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
            HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
            if (picture.getShapeType() == HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_PICTURE){
                if (picture.getImageDimension() != null) {
                   // how to get cell, which contains this picture
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How to find a cell for each picture in a sheet?**

**Update**, right now I write next working code:

```
HSSFPatriarch patriarch = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
if (patriarch != null) {
    // Loop through the objects
    for (HSSFShape shape : patriarch.getChildren()) {
        if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
            HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
            if (picture.getShapeType() == HSSFSimpleShape.OBJECT_TYPE_PICTURE){
                if (picture.getImageDimension() != null) {
                   // how to get cell, which contains this picture
                   if (picture.getImageDimension() != null) {
                        Row row = sheet.getRow(picture.getPreferredSize().getRow1());
                        if (row != null) {
                            Cell cell = row.getCell(picture.getPreferredSize().getCol1());

                            HSSFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
                            byte[] data = pictureData.getData();

                            File file = new File(PATH + picture.getFileName() + "." + pictureData.suggestFileExtension());
                            try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

                                if (!file.exists()) {
                                    file.createNewFile();
                                }

                                fop.write(data);
                                fop.flush();
                                fop.close();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need, like me, to assotiate a picture with a cell in future, try to use HashMap().

**Can some-one write any example for this task?** I want to find cells, contains a picture in excel's sheet. The trick in that, what picture is not cell's value.

Comment: try picture.getPictureData();

Comment: No, there is only data as byte[], format, mimetype, file extension, but no reference to any cell.

Comment: It may be a little late, but if you have a solution, you should add it as an answer, instead of editing the question

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280057/how-do-i-check-if-a-cell-contains-an-image-using-apache-poi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a cell contains an image using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280057/how-do-i-check-if-a-cell-contains-an-image-using-apache-poi)